# How to append and remove different text to a popup window?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a series of headshots for a list of artists and on each of the headshots is a button that opens up a popup window with their bio. Currently, I am creating the elements and appending them to the content div inside of the popup window. My issue is it currently takes two clicks for the bio text to be created and appended to the popup window. This is because the first click adds the event listener to the button and then the second click would then run the function for appending their bio. How do I append the text on the first click?

```js
const jessica1 = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vel venenatis turpis." ;
const jessica2 = "Vestibulum viverra tempus maximus. Nullam maximus ligula id ipsum posuere, ut vulputate tellus elementum.";

const genevieve1 = "In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aliquam nec metus in dui egestas dictum at non neque. Nunc gravida maximus ante semper facilisis.";
const genevieve2 = "Sed augue nisl, pellentesque vitae elementum sed, scelerisque pretium velit.";

const monica1 = "Mauris pharetra velit at feugiat pellentesque. Nullam non mi sed dolor molestie auctor.";

function togglePopUp() {
  const selection = document.getElementsByClassName("pink-btn");
  
  for (let i = 0; i < selection.length; i++) {
     selection[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        const popup = document.getElementById('popup-1');
        popup.classList.toggle('active');
        
        if (selection[i].value === "jessica") {
          let p1 = document.createElement('p');
          p1.append(jessica1);
          p1.classList.add('p-child');

          let p2 = document.createElement('p');
          p2.append(jessica2);
          p2.classList.add('p-child');
          
          const bio = document.getElementById('modal-body');
          bio.append(p1, p2)

          const title = document.createElement("h3");
          title.setAttribute('id', 'modal-title');
          title.append('Jessica');
          document.getElementById('modal-header').append(title);
        }
        
        else if (selection[i].value === "genevieve") {

                let p1 = document.createElement('p');
                p1.append(genevieve1);
                p1.classList.add('p-child');

                let p2 = document.createElement('p');
                p2.append(genevieve2);
                p2.classList.add('p-child');


                const bio = document.getElementById('modal-body');
                bio.append(p1, p2)

                const title = document.createElement("h3");
                title.setAttribute('id', 'modal-title');
                title.append('Genevieve');
                document.getElementById('modal-header').append(title);
        }
        
        else if (selection[i].value === "monica") {
                let p1 = document.createElement('p');
                p1.append(monica1);
                p1.classList.add('p-child');

                const bio = document.getElementById('modal-body');
                bio.append(p1);

                const title = document.createElement("h3");
                title.setAttribute('id', 'modal-title');
                title.append('Monica');
                document.getElementById('modal-header').append(title);
        }
        
        else if (selection[i].value === "close") {
                const body = document.getElementsByClassName('p-child');
                body.remove();

                const title = document.getElementById('modal-title');
                title.remove();
        }
     })
  }
}
```

```css
.card-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px 0;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(0, 1fr));
}

.card {
  display: inline-block;
}

.img-wrap {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 10px 10px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: #000;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.pink-btn {
  background: #fae5d8;
  color: #000;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-family: "BreweryCom-Black";
  font-size: 22px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  
}

.text-wrap {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  padding-top: 5px;
}


.popup .overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
}

.popup .content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 50%) scale(0);
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.popup .close-btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #222;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

.popup.active .overlay {
  display: block;
}

.popup.active .content {
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
}

.modal-body {
    text-align: left;
}

.modal-body p {
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div id="team-page" class="page-width">

  <div class="card-container">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="img-wrap">
        <img class="member-image" src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/barbara.png" alt="person" />
      </div>
        <button class="pink-btn" onclick="togglePopUp();" value="jessica">Jessica</button>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
      <div class="img-wrap">
        <img class="member-image" src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/barbara.png" alt="person" />
      </div>
        <button class="pink-btn" onclick="togglePopUp();" value="genevieve">Genevieve</button>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
      <div class="img-wrap">
        <img class="member-image" src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/barbara.png" alt="person" />
      </div>
        <button class="pink-btn" onclick="togglePopUp();" value="monica">Monica</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="popup" id="popup-1">
      <div class="overlay"></div>
      <div class="content">
          <button class="close-btn" onclick="togglePopUp();" value="close">&times;</button>
          <div id="modal-header"></div>
          <p id="modal-body" class="modal-body"></p>
      </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call your function in first mount then it will open the pop up with first click.

```
window.onload = togglePopUp;
```

```js
const jessica1 = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vel venenatis turpis." ;
const jessica2 = "Vestibulum viverra tempus maximus. Nullam maximus ligula id ipsum posuere, ut vulputate tellus elementum.";

const genevieve1 = "In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aliquam nec metus in dui egestas dictum at non neque. Nunc gravida maximus ante semper facilisis.";
const genevieve2 = "Sed augue nisl, pellentesque vitae elementum sed, scelerisque pretium velit.";

const monica1 = "Mauris pharetra velit at feugiat pellentesque. Nullam non mi sed dolor molestie auctor.";
window.onload = togglePopUp;

function togglePopUp() {
  const selection = document.getElementsByClassName("pink-btn");
  
  for (let i = 0; i < selection.length; i++) {
     selection[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        const popup = document.getElementById('popup-1');
        popup.classList.toggle('active');
        
        if (selection[i].value === "jessica") {
          let p1 = document.createElement('p');
          p1.append(jessica1);
          p1.classList.add('p-child');

          let p2 = document.createElement('p');
          p2.append(jessica2);
          p2.classList.add('p-child');
          
          const bio = document.getElementById('modal-body');
          bio.append(p1, p2)

          const title = document.createElement("h3");
          title.setAttribute('id', 'modal-title');
          title.append('Jessica');
          document.getElementById('modal-header').append(title);
        }
        
        else if (selection[i].value === "genevieve") {

                let p1 = document.createElement('p');
                p1.append(genevieve1);
                p1.classList.add('p-child');

                let p2 = document.createElement('p');
                p2.append(genevieve2);
                p2.classList.add('p-child');


                const bio = document.getElementById('modal-body');
                bio.append(p1, p2)

                const title = document.createElement("h3");
                title.setAttribute('id', 'modal-title');
                title.append('Genevieve');
                document.getElementById('modal-header').append(title);
        }
        
        else if (selection[i].value === "monica") {
                let p1 = document.createElement('p');
                p1.append(monica1);
                p1.classList.add('p-child');

                const bio = document.getElementById('modal-body');
                bio.append(p1);

                const title = document.createElement("h3");
                title.setAttribute('id', 'modal-title');
                title.append('Monica');
                document.getElementById('modal-header').append(title);
        }
        
        else if (selection[i].value === "close") {
                const body = document.getElementsByClassName('p-child');
                body.remove();

                const title = document.getElementById('modal-title');
                title.remove();
        }
     })
  }
}
```

```css
.card-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px 0;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(0, 1fr));
}

.card {
  display: inline-block;
}

.img-wrap {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 10px 10px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: #000;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.pink-btn {
  background: #fae5d8;
  color: #000;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-family: "BreweryCom-Black";
  font-size: 22px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  
}

.text-wrap {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  padding-top: 5px;
}


.popup .overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
}

.popup .content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 50%) scale(0);
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.popup .close-btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #222;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

.popup.active .overlay {
  display: block;
}

.popup.active .content {
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
}

.modal-body {
    text-align: left;
}

.modal-body p {
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div id="team-page" class="page-width">

  <div class="card-container">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="img-wrap">
        <img class="member-image" src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/barbara.png" alt="person" />
      </div>
        <button class="pink-btn" onclick="togglePopUp();" value="jessica">Jessica</button>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
      <div class="img-wrap">
        <img class="member-image" src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/barbara.png" alt="person" />
      </div>
        <button class="pink-btn" onclick="togglePopUp();" value="genevieve">Genevieve</button>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
      <div class="img-wrap">
        <img class="member-image" src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/barbara.png" alt="person" />
      </div>
        <button class="pink-btn" onclick="togglePopUp();" value="monica">Monica</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="popup" id="popup-1">
      <div class="overlay"></div>
      <div class="content">
          <button class="close-btn" onclick="togglePopUp();" value="close">&times;</button>
          <div id="modal-header"></div>
          <p id="modal-body" class="modal-body"></p>
      </div>
  </div>

</div>
```